# Iframe not rendering contents second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

I am rendering partial view though ajax in Iframe of Main View. And it works fine locally but after publish its works only first time second time it clears iframe body

Here is My Code:

```
  $('#editFaxdialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Edit PDF',
        height: 'auto',
        width: '80%',
        position: ['top', 50],
        draggable: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditPdf", "Fax")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    var frameSet = document.getElementById("editFaxFrame");
                    var iframedoc = frameSet.document;

                    if (frameSet.contentDocument)
                        iframedoc = frameSet.contentDocument;
                    else if (frameSet.contentWindow)
                        iframedoc = frameSet.contentWindow.document;

                    if (iframedoc){
                        iframedoc.open();
                        iframedoc.writeln(data);
                        iframedoc.close();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Error")';
                }
            });
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("#editFaxFrame").attr("src", '');
        }

    });
```

Comment: Is everytime when your iframe is opened postback happens?

Comment: Ya its happen even contents render for while and its gets clear

Comment: Is there any errors your getting?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: I can't see the problem outright without testing but obviously the problem is because the iframe is already created I would look in the "if (frameSet.contentDocument)" part of your code and make sure one of those conditions is met the second time.

Comment: did you try declaring `frameSet` variable outside of the function?

Comment: ya tried it also but still having same problem

Comment: can u make a fiddle demo fiddle for your code?

Answer (score 2):

I solved This Issue after so much r&d i put Settimeout() function on ajax success

```
 $('#editFaxdialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Edit PDF',
        height: 'auto',
        width: '80%',
        position: ['top', 50],
        draggable: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditPdf", "Fax")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    var frameSet = document.getElementById("editFaxFrame");
                    var iframedoc = frameSet.document;

                    if (frameSet.contentDocument)
                        iframedoc = frameSet.contentDocument;
                    else if (frameSet.contentWindow)
                        iframedoc = frameSet.contentWindow.document;

                    if (iframedoc){
                        iframedoc.open();
                        iframedoc.writeln(data);
                        iframedoc.close();
                    }
},400);
                },
                error: function () {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Error")';
                }
            });
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("#editFaxFrame").attr("src", '');
        }

    });
```